# Many-to-one relationships ComboBox filtering

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-models

Experts!

Having the following models.py

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)  

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Countries Uploaded'

class Users(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50) 
    cUsers = models.ForeignKey(Country)

    def __unicode__(self):
       return self.name

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Users on a country'

class GoalsinCountry(models.Model):
    Country = models.ForeignKey(VideoTopic)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)  
    descr = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Goals Topic'
```

I would like to filter out the users that belongs to a particular country and not all see all users when choosing a country on the combobox, and be able to save this information  to a sqlite3 db.

if I add the following code below Country = Models..

```
gUser = models.ForeignKey(Users)
```

Using the Django admin interface, will show all users, not filtering users based on the country they are..  Would this be possible to do with Django + Something else?  is there any working example/Tutorial - like the northwind MS Tutorial?

Thank you

Comment: Without using Ajax, is there any way to  limit based on what they choose above? like based on the countries they choose?